# How to get custom context information added by lambda authorizer in spring boot container? AWS Apigateway HTTP API

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, lambda-authorizer

We are using AWS ECS service run a container, we are running spring boot application in that container. This is exposed using AWS Apigateway HTTP API. This AWS Apigateway HTTP API is secured using lambda authorizer. Now I want to add some information to each request in lambda authorizer and I want to access that information in spring boot application method. How can I do that?

Comment: they should just be part of http headers, did you log the headers to check if the context headers exist?

Comment: instead of writing it in  lambda authorizer, you can write it in APIGateway and delegate it to particular request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

We have to set **context** field to an object(key-value pair) in lambda authorizer's response.

Then, we have to set parameter mapping as shown in the image. After that we can use Balu Vyamajala's code to get those values in spring boot controller's methods.

Answer (score 1):

[Custom Authorizer's](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-iam-and-lambda-authorizers-for-amazon-api-gateway-http-apis/) context will be passed as http headers and we can simply log the http headers to verify.

if policy returned by api gateway authorizer is

```
{
    "principalId": "user",
    "policyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:655648606120:nnnn1111ab/mystage/*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "context": {
        "userName": "My User Name",
        "userId": "myid",
        "groups": "Admin,User"
    }
}
```

They will be passed as http headers to backend

```
package com.test.config.interceptor;

import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

import com.amway.na.api.model.ApiEnum;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class ApiLoggerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        ApiEnum api = ApiEnum.get(request.getRequestURI());
        if (api.getLoggingRequired()) {

            StringBuilder headers = new StringBuilder();
            for (Enumeration<?> e = request.getHeaderNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
                String nextHeaderName = (String) e.nextElement();
                String headerValue = request.getHeader(nextHeaderName);
                headers.append("[").append(nextHeaderName).append(":").append(headerValue).append("] ");
            }
            log.debug("Execution of Api Starts: URI {} {}", request.getRequestURI(), headers);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

should display

```
[x-test-user-name:my user name] [x-test-groups:Admin,User] [x-test-user-id:myid] [accept:application/json, text/plain, */*] [accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br] [accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.9] [authentication:Beare...
```

This is tested against REST API not HTTP Api, But they should still be part of headers, names might be slightly different.